# Array from a jsonDecoder object

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary, swift4, decodable

This might be a very easy question (sorry!).

I would like to links a mySQL database to a Quiz App in Swift 4.
Therefore I connected to a service.php and got the information with decodable.

How can I access this information to show in a label? Do I have to make a new Array and append the objects?

```
import UIKit

struct Question: Codable {

let id: String?
let frage: String?
let antwort1: String?
let antwort2: String?
let antwort3: String?
let antwort4: String?
let correct: String?
let notiz: String?
let lernsektorID: String?
let lerneinheitID: String?
let lernbereichID: String?
let schwierigkeitID: String?
let redakteur: String?
let createdAt: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "ID"
    case frage = "Frage"
    case antwort1 = "Antwort1"
    case antwort2 = "Antwort2"
    case antwort3 = "Antwort3"
    case antwort4 = "Antwort4"
    case correct = "Correct"
    case notiz = "Notiz"
    case lernsektorID = "LernsektorID"
    case lerneinheitID = "LerneinheitID"
    case lernbereichID = "LernbereichID"
    case schwierigkeitID = "SchwierigkeitID"
    case redakteur = "Redakteur"
    case createdAt = "created_at"
}
}

var fragen = [Question]()

let url = "https://redaktion.pflegonaut.de/service.php"
let urlObj = URL(string: url)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) { (data, response, error) in
do {
     self.fragen = try JSONDecoder().decode([Question].self, from: data!)
// can I use .append() here?
// maybe in a for loop?

} catch {
    print(error)
}
}.resume()
```

So I can use the elements like:

```
//
// let randomizedQuestion = fragen.frage.randomElement()
// 
// questionOutlet.text = randomizedQuestion
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> `// NECESSARY?
>   var QuestionBankJson: [QuestionJson] {
>   var questionListJson = [QuestionJson]()
>   }`

No, just declare one array and name the struct simply `Question`

```
var questions = [Question]()
```

and assign

```
do {
  self.questions = try JSONDecoder().decode([Question].self, from: data!)
  print(self.questions[1].Frage!) 
} catch {
    print(error) // never print something meaningless like "we got an error"
}
```

Notes:

- Please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter.
- If you are responsible for the JSON declare also the keys lowercased otherwise use `CodingKeys`.
- Declare the struct members as much non-optional as possible.
- Never print a meaningless literal string when catching `Codable` errors. Print always the `error` instance.
- Use a better date string format than this arbitrary German format. UNIX time stamp, SQL date string or ISO8601 are sortable and can be even *decoded* to `Date`.

Comment: Thanks! I do my very best to make the code fitting the standard format.

Comment: But how can I access the "question" Array to questionOutlet.text = question[1].Frage

Comment: Declare the array on the top level of the class. Then access the array by index or in a loop depending on your design. (Consider that indices in Swift are zero-based).

Comment: I am sorrry i do not get it. Can you show me how to? I declared an Array at the top, but when I print it, it shows no results. In Addition to that I used CodingKeys but it did not fit to the codable protocol.

Comment: Better edit your question and add the relevant code.

Comment: According to my answer you have to write `fragen = try JSONDecoder().decode....` (in a real project `self.fragen = ....`).  No `var` keyword!. And the CodingKeys are wrong. The cases must match the struct members for example `case antwort1 = "Antwort1"` and you have to add `redakteur` and `created_at` if those keys are supposed to be decoded, too.

Comment: Thanks again for your support and time. I edited the code and added some comment down below. I hope you get my intention as i would like to show the Strings from "frage" (which means question) randomized in a label. Like first quiz round=> Outlet.text = frage[1], second quiz round=> Outlet.text = frage[4] and so on.

Comment: Ich verstehe (I understand) *frage* . That's another question. There are a few solutions. You could randomize the indexes with `let randomIndexes = fragen.indices.shuffled()`. Then in a loop `for index in randomIndexes { questionOutlet.text = fragen[index].frage` } populate the label and add the other logic to handle the answers.